# Evaluating $\int_{0}^{\infty}\sin(x)\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, bessel-functions

Playing around with some integrals, I stumbled across a cute one:
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}\sin(x)\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\,dx
$$
Substituting $z=\frac1x$ gives
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}\sin(x)\sin\left(\frac{1}x\right)\,dx = \int _0^{\infty} \frac{\sin(z)\sin\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)}{z^2}\,dz,
$$which Mathematica gave as $\frac{\pi}{2}J_1(2)$, where $J_1$ is the [Bessel function of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Bessel_functions_of_the_first_kind:_J%CE%B1). I'd be curious to see a derivation of this, as well as a rigorous proof the integral converges.